# swift 3: create a material-design-chip

Tags: ios, swift, material-design, cosmicmind

heyhey,

since a few days I attempt to create the "Material-Design-Chip", but only with half success.

The attempt with the most success I had, is to make a subclass from "Button" (Button is a subclass from UIButton created from [cosmicmind](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material) in his MaterialDesign-Framework for swift).

For the people who doesn't know I mean with "chips": [click here](https://material.google.com/components/chips.html#chips-specs)

my examples:

### The simple / non-deletable chip

```
import UIKit
import Material

class ChipButton: Button {
    override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()

        cornerRadiusPreset      = .cornerRadius5
        backgroundColor         = UIColor.lightGray
        titleColor              = Color.darkText.primary
        pulseAnimation          = .none
        contentEdgeInsets       = EdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 12, bottom: 0, right: 12)
        isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        titleLabel?.font        = RobotoFont.regular
        isOpaque                = true
    }
}
```

and to create this button:

```
let button = ChipButton()
    button.title = "default chip"

    view.layout(button).height(32).center(offsetY: -150)
```

### The contact-chip / icon-chip

```
import UIKit
import Material

class ChipIconButton: ChipButton {
    /*override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()

        contentEdgeInsets       = EdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 16, bottom: 0, right: 12)
    }*/

    public convenience init(image: UIImage?, title: String?){
        self.init()
        prepare(with: image, title: title)
    }

    private func prepare(with image: UIImage?, title: String?) {
        self.image = image
        self.title = title

        self.imageView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray // this works
        self.imageView?.cornerRadiusPreset = .cornerRadius4 // this works
        self.imageView?.tintColor  = Color.black // this doesn't work

        self.imageEdgeInsets    = EdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -8, bottom: 0, right: 12)
        self.titleEdgeInsets    = EdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        self.contentEdgeInsets  = EdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 8, bottom: 0, right: 12)
    }
}
```

here I want to

1. resize the UIImageView to the height of the chip (which is 32 points)

   ```
   I tried with self.imageView?.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 32, height: 32) but nothing changed
   ```
2. resize the UIImage little bit smaller (to 20 points)
3. to change the tintColor of the UIImage

   ```
   I tryed with self.imageView?.tintColor = Color.black but nothing changed
   ```

### The deletable chip

```
import UIKit
import Material

class ChipDeleteableButton: ChipButton {

    override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()

        self.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_close_white_24px")
        self.title = title

        //self.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 32, height: 32)
        self.imageView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        self.imageView?.cornerRadiusPreset = .cornerRadius4
        self.imageView?.tintColor  = Color.black

        self.imageEdgeInsets    = EdgeInsets(top: 0, left: self.frame.size.width, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        self.titleEdgeInsets    = EdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: self.frame.size.width)
        self.contentEdgeInsets  = EdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 8, bottom: 0, right: 12)
    }
}
```

here I tried to switch the positions of the label and with imageEdgeInsets and titleEdgeInsets, but self.frame.size.width returns a incorrect width (maybe couse of AutoLayout but i'm not sure)

### help

hope that somebody can help me!

ps. I'm little newbe at swift/xcode

Comment: i find out how to solve: 
> 3. to change the tintColor of the UIImage

for any buttontype (except .system-button) its necessary to add .withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate) to the img.

for example: 
    self.image = UIImage(named: "image-name").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)

Comment: UIImage(named: "image-name")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)

the question mark is important

Answer (score 1):

### The simple / non-deletable chip

here nothing changed.
look at the question.

### The contact-chip / icon-chip

```
import UIKit
import Material

class ChipIconButton: ChipButton {
    public convenience init(image: UIImage?, title: String?){
        self.init()
        prepare(with: image, title: title)
    }

    private func prepare(with image: UIImage?, title: String?) {
        //self.imageView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 60)
        let myThumb = image?.resize(toWidth: 20)?.resize(toHeight: 20)
        let shapeView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 32, height: 32))
        shapeView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        shapeView.cornerRadiusPreset = .cornerRadius5
        shapeView.zPosition = (self.imageView?.zPosition)! - 1

        self.addSubview(shapeView)


        self.image = myThumb?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        self.title = title
        self.imageView?.tintColor  = self.backgroundColor
        self.imageEdgeInsets    = EdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -28, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        self.titleEdgeInsets    = EdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        self.contentEdgeInsets  = EdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 12)
    }
}
```

and the creation-snipped:

```
open func prepareChipIconButton () {
    let icon: UIImage? = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_close_white_24px")
    let button = ChipIconButton(image: icon, title: "icon chip")
    view.layout(button).height(32).center(offsetY: 0)
}
```

### The deletable chip

```
import UIKit
import Material

class ChipDeleteableButton: ChipButton {

    override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()

        let img = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_close_white_24px").resize(toHeight:18)?.resize(toWidth: 18)
        let myThumb = img?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)

        self.image = myThumb
        self.title = title

        self.imageView?.tintColor  = self.backgroundColor
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(clickAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.imageView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }

    open func swapLabelWithImage() {
        let rightLableSize = self.titleLabel?.sizeThatFits((self.titleLabel?.frame.size)!)

        self.imageEdgeInsets    = EdgeInsets(top: 0, left: (rightLableSize?.width)! - 4, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        self.titleEdgeInsets    = EdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -54, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        self.contentEdgeInsets  = EdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 4)

        let shapeView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: self.imageEdgeInsets.left + 19, y: 6, width: 20, height: 20))
        shapeView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        shapeView.cornerRadius = shapeView.frame.size.width/2
        shapeView.zPosition = (self.imageView?.zPosition)! - 1
        shapeView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false


        self.addSubview(shapeView)
    }

    internal func clickAction(sender: ChipDeleteableButton) {
        print("do something")
    }
}
```

and the creation-snipped:

```
open func prepareChipDeleteableButton () {
    let button = ChipDeleteableButton()
    button.title    = "deleteable chip"
    button.swapLabelWithImage()

    view.layout(button).height(32).center(offsetY: 150)
}
```

### more info:

- the creation-function r called in my ViewController, in viewWillAppear()
- why i have a extra-function for my deletable-chip? - because i let AutoLayout do his job and after that i can get the necessary "String-width" of its label with let `rightLableSize = self.titleLabel?.sizeThatFits((self.titleLabel?.frame.size)!)`